# How can I drag and drop editor groups to customize the layout in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I'm not sure if this is already a feature or not. Right now, I have this layout :

- 2 column

  - First - 2 row (split vertical)
  - Second - 2 row (split vertical)

    - Second row 2 column (split horizontal)

So Like this

```
| 1 |_2_____|
|___| 4 | 5 |
|_3_|___|___|
```

My current windows(editor group) have multiple files open and I want them to stay open for now.

I would like to drag and drop editor group and change my layout with the mouse.
Something like this :

- 2 row,

  - first 2 column,
  - second 3 column

```
| 1   | 2   |
|_____|_____|
|_3_|_4_|_5_|
```

So you can move a file from an editor group using the left click (drag & drop style). On a mac, (ctrl+left click) would do the right click. But how I would imagine the feature, (cmd+option+left click+drag&drop) or (left click+drag&drop) on the [...] button at the right would trigger the drag and drop of that editor group which include all opened files in that editor group.

(This "..." button showing the dropdown option)
[image: The ... button]

Moving the full editor group would look like the same as moving the only file in that editor group.
That editor group get delete and move somewhere else. If the layout change from row and column, that's predictable like it would if you're dragging one file to an other "new editor group".

Same behaviour as having single file editor group, but you move all the current open tabs of that editor group somewhere else.

Btw, I know that I can use predefined layout or even keyboard shortcut, to do something similar, but I think those solution are not exactly what I want and can be tedious to get where I want it and changing layout with a mouse is easier than using the keyboard.

Maybe this feature is missing or I don't know how to use it, which I would be grateful to know. :)

Just for the sake of it, you can do that if you have empty space which I don't have when I have multiple files opened...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this feature exists *exactly*, but there seem to be plenty of things that could be helpful:

- You can move editor groups around by using the `View: Move Editor Group <Direction>` commands in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). They are also bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd><arrow key></kbd>.
- You can move tabs from an editor group into another editor group by holding <kbd>alt</kbd>, clicking the part of the editor tab strip that is "empty" (unoccupied by tab handles), and then dragging the stuff around. The mouse will have a tooltip that says the name of one of the tabs, and then "(+<number of other tabs that are being moved>)". Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to support creating new editor groups while dragging at the time of this writing, but you can combine this with the `View: New Editor Group <Direction>` commands in the command palette.

From my playing around, neither of those seem to be ideal. I don't feel like I have good control over the first option. The second option seems more controllable, but has a bit of extra steps in creating new empty editor groups. That's the best I could find right now.

Comment: Yeah, both option are not ideal and I'm not sure the solution I'm searching exist. I'm thinking about making a Feature request for that.

Comment: @Maxime4000 good idea. if you do, please comment here with a link to your feature request. I suggest you also show it to people on reddit's r/vscode and your friends. it can be difficult to get enough upvotes to get the feature-request added to the backlog in time.